# Issue in Audio File Transcription of HMS ML kit

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I am trying to implement Audio file transcription in HMS ML kit.
I have followed the official documentation and created the sample.
Still the service is returning me error code only

error code - 11103
I am using Honor 9 X pro
EMUI - 9.1.1

Below is the onError method where the control goes everytime.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    private val aftListener: MLRemoteAftListener = object : MLRemoteAftListener {
    override fun onResult(taskId: String, result: MLRemoteAftResult, ext: Any) {
        if (result.isComplete) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }

    override fun onError(taskId: String, errorCode: Int, message: String) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "onError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onInitComplete(taskId: String, ext: Any) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "onInitComplete", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

    override fun onUploadProgress(taskId: String, progress: Double, ext: Any) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onUploadProgress")
    }

    override fun onEvent(taskId: String, eventId: Int, ext: Any) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "onEvent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio file which you are providing as an input is too large.
Please go through below url to see the error codes
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/mlafterrors#ERR_AUDIO_FILE_SIZE_OVERFLOW